# SHA-256 thumbprint validation during scp file sending

Tags: scp

A file is send from ServerA to ServerB using self written automation tool via scp bash command. There is SHA-256 thumbprint required for ServerB host validation. What is the correct approach here to ensure in ServerA that the file will be send to ServerB via thumprint SHA-256?

Comment: That's quite broad question. What prevents you from comparing the fingerprint that you get from your `scp` client against the thumbprint you were provided?

Comment: Agreed but I want to validate the thumbprint during establishing connection for scp. Could not found thr correct approach to do that

Comment: *"validate the thumbprint during establishing connection for scp"* - And how that differs from what I've proposed in my comment?

Comment: My scp client is bahs scp command where I could not found how to do that. Could you please propose correct approach with example?

Comment: But I do not understand your problem – When you connect the first time, `scp` will show you fingerprint (thumbprint) of the server's host key and ask you to verify it. So do verify it – Unless you want to do it automatically, then see the answer by @muru.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks. I think I add in the description that self written automation tool will invoke scp command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only the key fingerprint, and not the public key itself, you can ask the server for its public keys and generate the corresponding fingerprints:

```
ssh-keyscan some.server | ssh-keygen -lf -
```

Then, you can grep for your fingerprint in that output. Example:

```
% ssh-keyscan github.com | ssh-keygen -lf- | grep -w 'SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8' && echo key matched
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-f97ce5b9
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-f97ce5b9
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-f97ce5b9
2048 SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8 github.com (RSA)
key matched
```

If the fingerprint matches, add the key to `.known_hosts`:

```
if ssh-keyscan some.server 2>/dev/null | ssh-keygen -lf - | grep -q 'SHA256:somekey'
then
    ssh-keyscan some.server >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
fi
```

Comment: I will accept this answer but the main idea is to make the validation during scp connection establishment such as insert the SHA-256 thumbprint in known-hosts file and make the scp and if it fails with unknown thumbprint message I will know that they does not match.

Comment: @JordanBorisov The built-in mechanism uses DNS resource records for that. Lookup SSHFP in `man ssh` and `VerifyHostKeyDNS` in `man ssh_config`. Otherwise you can just get the public key and put in the `known_hosts` file. After all, the public key should be public.

Comment: *"make the validation during scp connection establishment such as insert the SHA-256 thumbprint in known-hosts file and make the scp and if it fails with unknown thumbprint message..."* - That's exactly what the muru's answer shows, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the scenario is the following:
1. I have a SHA256 thumbprint.
2. Adding it to known-hosts.
3. Make scp connection and if it prompt me to accept a thumbprint the validation will fail. Otherwise will be ok.
The idea here is how to add SHA256 thumbprint to known_hosts?

Comment: @JordanBorisov You cannot add *"SHA256 thumbprint to known_hosts"*. `known_hosts` contains full public keys. This answers shows you how to add the full public key safely (be checking it against the "SHA256 thumbprint").